# Delete multiple rows based on a choice between a combination of two columns

Tags: sql-server, delete

I'm trying to write query do delete rows based on two columns:

```
  DELETE FROM us_TEST 
  WHERE [cell] in ('CA001018611', 'CA001135126')
  AND [date] IN ('2016-01-04', '2016-07-14')
```

However this matches when `[cell]` `'CA001018611'` is either `'2016-01-04'` or `'2016-07-14'`.

How can I modify this to delete `'CA001018611'` only when `[date]` is `'2016-01-04'` and `'CA001135126'` only when `[date]` is `'2016-07-14'`

Edit: **I have about ~100-300k rows to delete based on similar criteria.**

Comment: Are these values in another table or flat file? How do you plan on feeding them to the delete statement?

Comment: Or, will the rows to deleted be determined by a query of some sort? (in which case, you could presumably use the query to identify the rows).

Comment: why downvote ? haven't I understood the question ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are only looking to delete these rows based on the two conditions listed you can break this out into two separate queries.

```
DELETE FROM us_TEST WHERE [cell] = 'CA001018611' AND [date] = '2016-01-04';
DELETE FROM us_TEST WHERE [cell] = 'CA001135126' AND [date] = '2016-07-14';
```

If though, you have your criteria to find your rows to delete in tables there are other options. The table definitions and full requirements would be helpful.

Comment: This is the only sensible answer

Answer (score 4):

You need to add an `OR` to your SQL as follows:

```
DELETE FROM us_TEST
WHERE ([cell] = 'CA001018611' AND [date] = '2016-04-01')
OR    ([cell] = 'CA001135126' AND [date] = '2016-14-07');
```

Comment: If I have ~100k rows to drop would you still recommend this solution?

Comment: Index on [cell], index on [date], or possibly a compound one. Depending on your server's spec, I don't see it as a huge issue. Caveat: Not a SQL Server expert - more of an Open Source man :-) Maybe run a few tests before launching in production?

Comment: @R.M. You could test for yourself.

Answer (score 3):

A join might be the best performance

```
delete * 
from table t 
join FROM ( values ('CA001018611', '2016-01-04'), ('CA001135126', '2016-07-14') 
          ) q(cl, dt) 
  on t.cl = q.cl 
 and t.dt = q.dt
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this help?

```
DELETE FROM us_TEST 
WHERE ([cell] = 'CA001018611' AND [date] = '2016-01-04') 
      OR 
      ([cell] = 'CA001135126' AND [date] = '2016-07-14')
```